# Cache JNI environment in a multithreading application

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have an android application using multiple threads (e.g. ui thread an networking thread). Now I want both threads to call native functions. Also some native functions will call java functions.

For this a `JNIEnv*` is required, which differs from thread to thread. But I assume that calling `GetEnv()` is pretty inefficient.

Is there a way to cache the `JNIEnv*`s for each thread and then determine, in which thread we are on (in the native function) to use the correct cached `JNIEnv*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT cache the JNIEnv and should be using AttachCurrentThread() on the cached JVM*.  If the native thread is already attached I believe this function is equivalent to a NOOP.

```
if ((*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void **)(&env), NULL) == JNI_OK) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the performance of `AttachCurrentThread()`? Is it remarkable slow?

Comment: If the thread is already attached, its as fast as the no-op instruction.  So, yes its as fast as its going to get.  There maybe a performance issue if you need to attach to a bunch of newly created threads, however, I doubt that JNI would be your bottleneck at that point.